# Passing context into a react SFC using Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to pass context into a SFC as outlined in the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#referencing-context-in-stateless-functional-components), but typescript is freaking out about it. I've reproduced [the issue on codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/l91l2mqp9q?module=%2Fcomponents%2FShirt.tsx), and inlined relevant info bellow. So-

### How do I tell Typescript `Chill, everything will be okay`?

#### Error Message:

`Property 'contextTypes' does not exist on type '(props: ShirtProps, context: any) => Element'.`

#### A simplified version of my `component` looks like this:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import * as PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { ShirtProps as Props } from '../types';

// tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
export const Shirt = (props: Props, context: any) => {
  return (
    <h1>Example text size is {props.scale}</h1>
  );
};

// Typescript throws the following warning:
// Property 'contextTypes' does not exist on type '(props: ShirtProps, context: any) => Element'.
Shirt.contextTypes = {
  parallaxController: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default Shirt;
```

Thanks!

**Any other tips are welcome- I'm just getting started with Typescript AND React.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you tell it that Shirt is an SFC it should compile (with the type `React.SFC<Props>`):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { ShirtProps as Props } from '../types';

// tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
export const Shirt: React.SFC<Props> = (props: Props, context: any) => {
  return (
    <h1>Example text size is {props.scale}</h1>
  );
};

Shirt.contextTypes = {
  parallaxController: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default Shirt;
```

Comment: Awesome, that does the trick! Can you provide any context as to why that is necessary?